# Serialize field as attribute of an element

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I have

```
[XmlRoot("root")]
class Person
{
  [XmlAttribute("name")] 
  public strig Name {get;set;}
}
```

After serialization I will get:

```
<root name="...">
</root>
```

Any simple way to get

```
<root>
  <general name="...">
</root>
```

?

Options for me are: make other class, using IXmlSerializable, etc

It's posible to have something like below ?

```
// code not valid
[XmlElement("general")]
[XmlAttribute("name")] 
public strig Name {get;set;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I will stay with IXmlSerializable, as:

```
[XmlRoot("root")]
class Person : IXmlSerializable
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name {get;set;}

        public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema() {
            return null;
        }

        public void ReadXml( XmlReader reader ) {
        ...
        }

        public void WriteXml( XmlWriter writer ) {
            writer.WriteStartElement( "root" );
            writer.WriteStartElement( "general", null );
            writer.WriteAttributeString( "action", Action );
            ...
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To get an element inside you need to use the XmlElement attribute.  So if you create a 'general' class containing an XmlAttribute("name") property.  You can then add this to your Person class.

```
[XmlRoot("root")]
class Person
{
    [XmlElement("general")]
    public General General {get; set;}
}
class General
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")] 
    public strig Name {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This option I try to avoid. Another options is to implement IXmlSerializer.